# SQL query checking columns in first table or looking up rows in second table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So I have the following situation:

I have a post model which always has 2 or 4 arguments

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has two columns, status and published (boolean)
  has_many :arguments
end
```

and an argument model

```
class Argument < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has moderated column (boolean) and text
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and I wonder if I can write a query to get posts with following conditions:

1) the post has unmoderated arguments and first of those, ordered by id (not updated_at) belongs to user with `id = 5` (for instance)

------ OR ------

2) the post `status = 1 and published = true`

PS.: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated to SQL:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   posts p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (post_id)
          post_id, user_id
   FROM   arguments
   WHERE  moderated = FALSE
   ORDER  BY post_id, id
   ) a ON a.post_id = p.id AND a.user_id = 5
WHERE  a.post_id IS NOT NULL OR        -- condition 1
      (a.status = 1 and a.published);  -- condition 2
```

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Why the `LEFT JOIN`?

If there was just condition `1)`, we could simplify:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   posts p
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ...
   ) a ON a.post_id = p.id AND a.user_id = 5;
```

But you added the alternative (not additional) condition `2)`. If we would use a plain `[INNER] JOIN`, posts not passing condition `1)` would be dropped from the selection immediately and never get their second chance. I added redundant parentheses ([operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) would work for us without parentheses) and a line break to point out that this is "the other way in":

```
(a.status = 1 and a.published)
```

Of course, we have to add the check for condition `1)` now:

```
a.post_id IS NOT NULL
```

This works without duplicating rows because the subquery returns *exactly 1 or 0* rows per post (and not more).

This is *one* way to solve it. Should be an excellent choice for only few attributes per post (2 - 4) and a non-trivial number of qualifying attributes. Depending on your actual data distribution there may be other, faster query techniques:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: I've changed it a bit and after a little testing, I made it work :) Thank you so much for your time and help and I apologize for a lousy written question. The only thing I want to point out is that I needed to use tables' names in plural form, like 'FROM posts p' and the same with the arguments table

Comment: @JustMichael: That seems to be the Ruby naming convention. Personally, I prefer singular terms for tables. the plural adds nothing but longer names. (I also wouldn't use the non-descriptive `id` as column name, like some ORMs do.)

Comment: Yeah it's a rails convention and thanks for explaining

Comment: it works as expected but I wanted to ask one more thing, I've read some info saying that left join returns left records even if the right ones are null so I wonder if this query can return posts that have no joined arguments? Or what am I missing?

Comment: @JustMichael: What you have heard about `LEFT JOIN` is exactly right. I added a rationale.